# Should all of my palicos have equipment?

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate

When you have your first stringer squad, you can give them equipment, but you can only take one other 1st stringer with you and your main palico on quests.

You also can't send first stringers out as "meownster hunters".

Is there any reason to have your other first stringers besides your sub and main equipped for combat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you switch around your deployed palicos a lot, no, there's no reason to equip your other first ringers.